# Update database with JPA

Tags: jpa, updates

I'm trying to update my (MySQL) database but it does'nt work.

Persistence code (called by a JSF managed bean):

```
@Override
    public void changeEntrepriseStatut(int idEntreprise, int newStatut) {
        Entreprise entr = em.find(Entreprise.class, idEntreprise);
        em.persist(entr);
        entr.setEntrepriseStatutInscription(newStatut);
        em.merge(entr);
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's working? What's not? Please be specific.

Comment: Please provide the exact issues you have here. Also, I don't see any `<h:form>` here.

Comment: If `changeEntrepriseStatut()` method is properly called with proper arguments, then the code of the caller is completely irrelevant and only adds noise to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have an open transaction. 
How you can do that does depend on how you manage your beans with jsf. There are at least four ways.

1. @ManagedBean - is the less power full possibility you should never do an operation which needs a transaction in there. (Call an EJB for example)
2. CDI beans - more powerfull but does also not have support for transactions build in when I am correct (not sure what the status of JavaEE7 is)
3. EJB - this is probably the easiest way, because of the support for @Transactional
4. Spring - never used that, if your using that please search the net for how to do that.

Additional never call em.persist on an already persisted bean. Just drop the line.